# configurando EntityFramework C# e SQL Server

Tags: entity-framework

"the element 'entityFramework' has invalid child element 'providers'.
    List of possible elementes expected: 'contexts'."

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt... Somente com a descrição da `exception` não é possível te ajudar, acrescente o código do arquivo de configuração das entidades...

Comment: [Edite sua pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/174619/54880), colocando de maneira clara a atual configuração para que possa ser apontado o problema.

Answer (score 1):

no projeto onde esta seu web config se estiver setado como principal deve conter isso em sua connections string  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

exemplo:

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="nomeconexao" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

se tiver duvida poste seu código